# How to install older version of azure service fabric Runtime? I need 5.6 version

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Where can I find a specific version of Service Fabriс, I need 5.6 runtime and 2.6 sdk version. Is there any download list for Service Fabric versions? 
I found the link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/06/20/release-of-sdk-2-6-220-and-runtime-5-6-220-refresh-for-windows , but there no link for downloading this version. Every link leads to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

https://servicefabricsdkstorage.blob.core.windows.net/public-release-notes/Microsoft%20Azure%20Service%20Fabric%20Release%20Notes%20-%20SDK%202.6.220%20-%20Runtime%205.6.220.docx

Here is a link where the downloading links of service fabric Runtime, SDK and VS Tools can be found.

So the algorithm for seeking download links:

1. Find the release update on Azure
   site.(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/06/20/release-of-sdk-2-6-220-and-runtime-5-6-220-refresh-for-windows/
   in my case)
2. Find release notes of a specific release.
3. Download Release Notes
4. Find Download links at the end of a document.

Answer (score 0):

Can use Web Platform Installer to install different versions of Service Fabric SDK together with runtime. If you don't want to install the corresponding SDK, only runtime, actually you can go to Web Platform Installer's folder to find the package, such as "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_6_5_CU5".

[image: Search result of 'service fabric' in Web Platform Installer]